# Values of a property at design time, doesn't appear at run time

Tags: delphi, class, components

I have the following component which contains a property derived from a custom class:

```
unit MyComponentTest3;

interface

uses  Windows, ExtCtrls,Classes,Controls;

type

  TMyClass3 = class
    myString: string;
    myNumber: double;
  end;

  TMyComponentTest3 = class(TCustomPanel)
  private
    FMyProperty: TMyClass3;

    procedure SetMyProperty(Value: TMyClass3);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;

    procedure SetMyPropertyPublic(AmyString: string; AmyNumber: double);
  published
    property MyProperty: TMyClass3 read FMyProperty write SetMyProperty;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation


procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('MyComponents', [TMyComponentTest3]);
end;

{ TMyComponentTest3 }

constructor TMyComponentTest3.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;

  FMyProperty:= TMyClass3.Create;

end;

destructor TMyComponentTest3.Destroy;
begin
  FMyProperty.Free;

  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyComponentTest3.SetMyProperty(Value: TMyClass3);
begin
with FMyProperty do
  begin
    myString:= Value.myString;
    myNumber:= Value.myNumber;
  end;
end;

procedure TMyComponentTest3.SetMyPropertyPublic(AmyString: string;
  AmyNumber: double);
var
  auxMyProperty: TMyClass3;
begin

  auxMyProperty:= TMyClass3.Create;

  with auxMyProperty do
  begin
    myString:= AmyString;
    myNumber:= AmyNumber;
  end;

  SetMyProperty(auxMyProperty);

  auxMyProperty.Free;

end;

end.
```

It works fine, but when I set the values of the property at design time and run the program the values disappear. The same problem I get if I set the values of the component, save everything and when I load the values are not there anymore...

I guess the problem is because I am creating an instance of the custom class all the time, but I am not sure, and I don't know how to get around that. Do anyone has an idea of what can I do?

Comment: Any reason not to make `TMyClass3` a record instead of a class?

Comment: This is only a simple example, in my real code it is more complicated...

Comment: @J... No matter how complex it is, the key determining factor is whether you want value or reference assignment semantics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TMyClass3` needs to derive from `TPersistent` in order to be streamable in a DFM.  It should also optionally override the virtual `Assign()` method, which `SetMyProperty()` would then be able to call.

Try this:

```
unit MyComponentTest3;

interface

uses
  Windows, ExtCtrls, Classes, Controls;

type

  TMyClass3 = class(TPersistent)
  private
    FMyString: string;
    FMyNumber: double;
  public
    procedure Assign(Source: TPersistent); override;
  published 
    property myString: string read FMyString write FMyString;
    property myNumber: double read FMyNumber write FMyNumber;
  end;

  TMyComponentTest3 = class(TCustomPanel)
  private
    FMyProperty: TMyClass3;

    procedure SetMyProperty(Value: TMyClass3);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;

    procedure SetMyPropertyPublic(AmyString: string; AmyNumber: double);
  published
    property MyProperty: TMyClass3 read FMyProperty write SetMyProperty;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation


procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('MyComponents', [TMyComponentTest3]);
end;

{ TMyClass3 }

procedure TMyClass3.Assign(Source: TPersistent);
begin
  if Source is TMyClass3 then
  begin
    with TMyClass3(Source) do
    begin
      Self.FMyString := myString;
      Self.FMyNumber := myNumber;
    end;
  end else
    inherited;
end;

{ TMyComponentTest3 }

constructor TMyComponentTest3.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FMyProperty := TMyClass3.Create;
end;

destructor TMyComponentTest3.Destroy;
begin
  FMyProperty.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyComponentTest3.SetMyProperty(Value: TMyClass3);
begin
  FMyProperty.Assign(Value);
end;

procedure TMyComponentTest3.SetMyPropertyPublic(AmyString: string; AmyNumber: double);
begin
  with MyProperty do
  begin
    myString := AmyString;
    myNumber := AmyNumber;
  end;  
end;

end.
```

Comment: Nothing... it seems that it doesn't reach this assign procedure, the values are still not appearing at run time and I put a message inside the assign procedure to check and it never shows it

Comment: `Assign()` is not going to be called, because the property setter is not called during DFM streaming. That suggestion was merely to cleanup your setter and implement better encapsulation. Your problem is something else, but you still need to start with the basics - derive from `TPersistent`, make the sub-values themselves be published properties, etc. What you describe suggests the values are not being saved to the DFM to begin with, thus are not present to be loaded later.

Comment: A simple way to test your component's DFM streaming capability at design-time is to drop the component onto a Form, set the properties as needed, right-click the Form Designer and choose "View As Text" and verify the values are present, then right-click again and choose "View As Form" and verify the values are in the component. If your values do not work as expected then something is broken.

Comment: Only the published properties will be saved with the component? I have a property that it is an array and I cannot publish it, however I need that its values be saved as well... Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Yes, only `published` properties using supported data types are streamed by default. To stream other data, you need to override the virtual [`DefineProperties()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.Classes.TPersistent.DefineProperties) method to provide custom streaming.

Comment: does it work with arrays? I searched on the web, but it seems that it is not possible...

Comment: Like I said, you would have to provide custom streaming. You can stream the data however you want. Depending on what your array actually is, you would likely use `TFiler::DefineBinaryProperty()` so you can write the array data however you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor TMyComponentTest3.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FMyProperty := TMyClass3.Create;
  FMyProperty.SetSubComponent(True);
end;
```